# How to get all combinations of a string with fixed character position?

Tags: php, string, permutation, combinations

I need to find a way to produce all combinations of a string with a particular character to always display in PHP.

For example, given a string 'ABCD', and I want to get all combinations of the string with the character 'B' present, I want to get:

array(' B  ',
' BC ',
' BCD',
' B D',
'AB  ',
'ABC ',
'AB D',
'ABCD')

The missing characters are replaced with spaces.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

It's easy if you think of each letter in the string being either "on" or "off" - like a bit in a binary number.  In fact, you can represent it as such.

So think of your string as a four bit number, which can be anything from `0b0000 = 0 = ""` to `0b1111 = 15 = "ABCD"`.  Then you can just run through all the numbers from 0 to 15, and find the respective "permutation" by seeing what bits are set.

For example, "permutation" 6: `0b0110 -> " BC "`

Hope that helps!

PS:  If this is homework, you should tag it as such - it's a bit of a faux pas around here not to.

PPS:  Your "[permutations](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Permutation)" are actually "[combinations.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Combination)"  Linked to Wikipedia just in case you're curious.